Open FGA: Custom Role on a multi-layer structure?
im trying to tie together the following model:
model
  schema 1.1

type user

type group
  relations
    define member: [user]

type role
  relations 
    define assignee: [user, group#member]

type holding_company
  relations
    define basic_read: [user, group#member, role#assignee] or full_read
    define full_read: [user, group#member, role#assignee]
    define subsidiary_list: [user, group#member, role#assignee]
    define subsidiary_create: [user, group#member, role#assignee]
    define subsidiary_delete: [user, group#member, role#assignee]
    
type subsidiary
  relations
    define parent: [holding_company]
    define order_list: [user, group#member, role#assignee]
    define order_create: [user, group#member, role#assignee]
    define staff_list: [user, group#member, role#assignee]
    define staff_create: [user, group#member, role#assignee]

type order
  relations
    define parent: [subsidiary]
    define read_basic: [user, group#member, role#assignee] or read_full
    define read_full: [user, group#member, role#assignee]
    #define read_financials: [user, group#member, role#assignee]
    #define read_pii: [user, group#member, role#assignee]
    define edit: [user, group#member, role#assignee]
    define submit: [user, group#member, role#assignee]
    define revert: [user, group#member, role#assignee]
    define cancel: [user, group#member, role#assignee]

type staff
  relations
    define parent: [subsidiary, holding_company]
    define read_basic: [user, group#member, role#assignee] or read_full
    define read_full: [user, group#member, role#assignee]
    define edit: [user, group#member, role#assignee]
    define terminate: [user, group#member, role#assignee]

For example, im trying to:

create a role BigBoss applicable only to holding-company:CocaCola and this role can do everything...
at the same time, create the role LocalHRDeputy that can only staff_list,staff_read_full and staff=>edit over the subsidiary:doritos of the holding-company:pepsiCo
crate the role OrderReviewer that can order=>read_full of any subsidiary of the holding_company:Mercedes

Can someone clarify how does this would work?
